# .NET WebClient.DownloadData get file type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, webclient

In order to handle cases of downloading data from a url that has no file extension,
I need to know what the file type is.

for example, how can the WebClient.DownloadData method reveal that it downloaded a png [edit: jpeg] image using the url below?

[https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTw4P3HxyHR8wumE3lY3TOlGworijj2U2DawhY9wnmcPKnbmGHg](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcTw4P3HxyHR8wumE3lY3TOlGworijj2U2DawhY9wnmcPKnbmGHg)

I did not find anything in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that describes how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't, directly.

If you trust the headers the web server sends back, you could use a different HTTP client (e.g. `WebRequest` or `HttpClient`) to make the entire response available rather than just the body. You can then look at the Content-Type header.

Other than that, you'll need to look at the content itself. Various file types have "magic numbers" which you could use to identify the file - they're typically at the start of the file, and if you only have a limited set of file types to look for, this may well be a viable approach. It won't be able to identify *all* file types though.

As an example, the first four bytes of the image you've linked to are ff d8 ff e0. That reveals that actually it's not a jpeg image. As it happens, the server response *also* included a header of `content-type: image/jpeg`.

Comment: Thank you for the through answer. I edited my question to state that its a jpeg I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 13):

If you trust the header information, this is possible to do using `WebClient`—you don't need to use `HttpClient`:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var result = webClient.DownloadData(url);
var contentType = webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"];

if (contentType != null && 
    contentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // it's probably an image
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use **HttpClient** for doing this GET request.

> Sample code:

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcTw4P3HxyHR8wumE3lY3TOlGworijj2U2DawhY9wnmcPKnbmGHg");
            var filetype = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
            var imageArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

On the above code, filetype variable has the file type and also extension as image/JPEG or image/PNG etc.

Comment: thank you. this is the answer that I have chosen to use. though I marked Jon's as the answer due to the information that was included there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [FindMimeFromData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107.aspx) API. Here is the snippet. It may help you.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var result = webClient.DownloadData(new Uri("url"));
IntPtr mimeout;
int result2 = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, "sample", result, 4096, null, 0, out mimeout, 0);
if (result2 != 0)
    throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(result2);
string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeout);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeout);
Console.WriteLine(mime);
```

And here is the API declaration. (Copied from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata))

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
static extern int FindMimeFromData(IntPtr pBC, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzUrl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeParamIndex = 3)] 
byte[] pBuffer, int cbSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]  string pwzMimeProposed, int dwMimeFlags, out IntPtr ppwzMimeOut, int dwReserved);
```

Comment: ... and thus another application with a dependency on Internet Explorer is born :D